# opencv and c++ visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have this code it work good.

When video length less than 1 minute and video size its 165 KB
When I change the video with other length 2 minute and size 15 MB OR another one same length with size 5 MB its show to me

project has stop working

this my code

```
# include "windows.h" 
# ifdef _CH_ 
# pragma package < opencv > 
# endif 
# include "windows.h" 
# ifndef _EiC 
# include "cv.h" 
# include "cvAux.h" 
# include "highgui.h" 
# include "cxcore.h" 
# include < stdio.h > 
# include < ctype.h > 
# endif 


// x?y?

int getpixel ( IplImage * image , int x , int y , int * h , int * s , int * v ) { 
* h = ( uchar ) image -> imageData [ y * image -> widthStep + x * image -> nChannels ] ; 
* s = ( uchar ) image -> imageData [ y * image -> widthStep + x * image -> nChannels + 1 ] ; 
* v = ( uchar ) image -> imageData [ y * image -> widthStep + x * image -> nChannels + 2 ] ; 
return 0 ; 
} 
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 



int main ( int argc , char * * argv ) { 
CvCapture * capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("a.avi") ; 
IplImage * image = 0; 
IplImage * HSV = 0 ; 

/*
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("greatwave.png", 1);
Mat mtx(img); // convert IplImage* -> Mat
*/
if ( argc == 1 || ( argc == 2 && strlen ( argv [ 1 ] ) == 1 && isdigit ( argv [ 1 ] [ 0 ] ) ) ) { 
//capture = cvCaptureFromCAM ( argc == 2 ? argv [ 1 ] [ 0 ] - '0' : 0 ) ; 
} 
else if ( argc == 2 ) { 
//capture = cvCaptureFromAVI ( argv [ 1 ] ) ; 
} 

if ( !capture ) { 
fprintf ( stderr , "Could not initialize capturing.../n" ) ; 
return - 1 ; 
} 

printf ( "Hot keys: /n" "/tESC - quit the program/n" ) ; 

//Normal

cvNamedWindow ( "Normal" , CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ) ; 


//Condensation------------------------------------------------- 

int DP = 2 ; // 

int MP = 2 ; // 

int SamplesNum = 300 ; // 


CvConDensation * ConDens = cvCreateConDensation ( DP , MP , SamplesNum ) ; 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------- 


//Condensation----------------------------------- 

CvMat * lowerBound ; // 

CvMat * upperBound ; // 

lowerBound = cvCreateMat ( 2 , 1 , CV_32F ) ; 
upperBound = cvCreateMat ( 2 , 1 , CV_32F ) ; 
//640*480 

cvmSet ( lowerBound , 0 , 0 , 0.0 ) ; 
cvmSet ( upperBound , 0 , 0 , 640.0 ); 
cvmSet ( lowerBound , 1 , 0 , 0.0 ) ; 
cvmSet ( upperBound , 1 , 0 , 480.0 ) ; 

cvConDensInitSampleSet ( ConDens , lowerBound , upperBound ) ; 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------- 


//------------------------------ 

for ( int i = 0 ; i < SamplesNum ; i++ ) { 
ConDens -> flSamples [ i ] [ 0 ] += 320.0 ; 
ConDens -> flSamples [ i ] [ 1 ] += 240.0 ; 
} 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------- 


//---------------------------- 

ConDens -> DynamMatr [ 0 ] = 1.0 ;
ConDens->DynamMatr [ 1 ] = 0.0 ; 
ConDens -> DynamMatr [ 2 ] = 0.0 ;
ConDens->DynamMatr [ 3 ] = 1.0 ; 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------- 


for ( ;; ) { 
IplImage* frame = 0 ; 
int c ; 
int X , Y , XX , YY ; 
int H , S , V ; 

frame = cvQueryFrame ( capture ) ; 
if ( !frame ) { 
break ; 
} 

if ( !image ) { 
image = cvCreateImage ( cvGetSize ( frame ) , 8 , 3 ) ; 
image -> origin = frame -> origin ; 
HSV = cvCreateImage ( cvGetSize ( frame ) , 8 , 3 ) ; 
HSV -> origin = frame -> origin ; 
} 

cvCopy ( frame , image , 0 ) ; 
cvCvtColor ( image , HSV , CV_BGR2HSV ) ; 

//?--------------------------------------------------- 

for ( int i = 0 ; i < SamplesNum ; i++ ) { 

X = ( int ) ConDens -> flSamples [ i ] [ 0 ] ; 
Y = ( int ) ConDens -> flSamples [ i ] [ 1 ] ; 

if ( X >= 0 && X <= 640 && Y >= 0 && Y <= 480 ) { //

getpixel ( HSV , X , Y , &H , &S , & V ) ; 
if ( H <= 19 && S >= 48 ) { // //H<=19 S>=48 

cvCircle ( image , cvPoint ( X , Y ) , 4 , CV_RGB ( 255 , 0 , 0 ) , 1 ) ; 
ConDens -> flConfidence [ i ] = 1.0 ; 
} 
else { 
ConDens -> flConfidence [ i ] = 0.0 ; 
} 
} 
else { 
ConDens -> flConfidence [ i ] = 0.0 ; 
} 
} 

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 


//

cvConDensUpdateByTime ( ConDens ) ; 

cvShowImage ( "Normal" , image ) ; 
c = cvWaitKey ( 20 ) ; 

if ( c == 27 ) { 
break ; 
} 
} 

//------------------------------------ 

cvReleaseImage ( &image ) ; 
cvReleaseImage ( &HSV ) ; 
cvReleaseConDensation ( &ConDens ) ; 
cvReleaseMat ( &lowerBound ) ; 
cvReleaseMat ( &upperBound ) ; 
cvReleaseCapture ( &capture ) ; 
cvDestroyWindow ( "Normal" ) ; 

//--------------------------------------------- 


return 0 ; 
} 

# ifdef _EiC 
main ( 1 , "condensation.cpp" ) ; 
# endif
```

also when o comment this

```
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < SamplesNum ; i++ ) { 

    X = ( int ) ConDens -> flSamples [ i ] [ 0 ] ; 
    Y = ( int ) ConDens -> flSamples [ i ] [ 1 ] ; 

    if ( X >= 0 && X <= 640 && Y >= 0 && Y <= 480 ) { //

    getpixel ( HSV , X , Y , &H , &S , & V ) ; 
    if ( H <= 19 && S >= 48 ) { // //H<=19 S>=48 

    cvCircle ( image , cvPoint ( X , Y ) , 4 , CV_RGB ( 255 , 0 , 0 ) , 1 ) ; 
    ConDens -> flConfidence [ i ] = 1.0 ; 
    } 
    else { 
    ConDens -> flConfidence [ i ] = 0.0 ; 
    } 
    } 
    else { 
    ConDens -> flConfidence [ i ] = 0.0 ; 
    } 
    }
```

program work without do my idea of track object

i have windows 8

please comment if u dont understand some thing

Comment: no idea, but you should start using the (not so) new C++ syntax for OpenCV stuff...

Comment: did u think my pc need more speed for run it ? its loop 300 loops in all frame

Comment: no, i don't think that you'll run out of memory or something unless you have a very very old pc. But since you're running Win8, you should be ok. Hint: if you remove a code block and it works, probably the error is there! and again, start using C++ syntax. Many things have changed and got better.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what does you code do?

Comment: link the video that gives you the problem

Comment: i forget i serach about the site

Comment: Code too old, I cannot run it. I'll let it go.. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is related to the declaration of `IplImage *frame` inside the `for loop`. When the size of your video length increases then, your memory gets full. Because you are continuously creating new `frames` inside the `for loop` without freeing the memory allocated to them.

You should declare `IplImage *frame` outside the `for loop` and then release the memory allocated to it outside the `for loop`.

**ADVICE:** Do not use old C-standards of OpenCV. Use the new C++ standards where you have to declare an image as `Mat image`. Then, you don't need to think about freeing memory because it does all the stuff itself.

Comment: I tried to run your code but there are several things missing. Please post only the relevant part only so that, I can test at my system.

Comment: did u import opencv ?

Comment: @MohamedMohamed: I would strongly recommend you to use `Mat image` because then you don't need to think about memory management. Even I have experienced such things and the problem was related to Memory leak due to improper handling of `IplImage`.

Comment: also i use video name a.avi  add it in project folder